# react-bootstrap modal dialog inline style

Tags: styles, react-bootstrap

Is it possible to set the 'style' attribute on a modal such that it applies an inline style to the modal?  When I try using this:

```
                 <Modal
                    ref="myModal"
                    className="modal-screen-cleared"
                    backdrop="static"
                    dialogClassName="modal-screen-cleared"
                    style={{zIndex:1001}}
                    backdropStyle={{opacity: 1, zIndex:1000, backgroundColor: "#cccccc", height: "100%"}}
                > ...</Modal>
```

the `style` attribute is never applied.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `react-bootstrap` and not `react-modal-bootstrap`? `react-bootstrap` does not take any `backdropStyle` attribute and `react-modal-bootstrap` ***seems*** (I could be wrong) like it doesn't take any `style` attribute. Which library are you using?

Comment: it's definitely react-bootstrap.  the backdropStyle isn't advertised, but it does work.

Comment: that's weird. What happens if you remove the `backdropStyle`? Does the `style` work then?

Comment: no, it will completely remove the applied style.

Comment: I really just want to add some kind of property to the backdrop div.  could be an id or a className... anything :)

Comment: I don't know what to suggest. I have tried this locally and it works. If `style` isn't being applied then something is wrong in your application. Check node versions, what node modules are installed, which ones you import, etc. If needed, edit the node module and do some console log to see what's happening.

Comment: I think you're not understanding me.  style _IS_ being applied... the className is the thing that isn't being applied.

Comment: Well it's a bit confusing because in your question you say *the `style` attribute is never applied.* Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r79zog32/), the `className` and `style` is being applied, but the `backdropStyle` does not.

Comment: Shit. My bad. Meant to say class name.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. For me it works and it also works in that demo I linked. Did you see it?